# Is there a call limit to accessing LinkedIn share counts?

Tags: linkedin-api

When using `https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?format=json&url=` to access an article's sharecount, is there an api daily limit?

We noticed that the time it was taking to retrieve count data was taking as much as 20 seconds on our production server.  We added logic to cache the number of counts, and the 20 second delay stopped the next day.  We are left wondering though what the limit might be (we can't seem to find it in your documentation).